# Unable to configure head collection and snapshot collection name in Javers framework in spring boot

Tags: javers

I am using spring boot(v 2.6.6), java11 and javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo(6.9.1). I tried changing the name of the collections that Javers creates by default in MongoDB as mentioned in the [javers docs](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-persistence-mongo/src/test/groovy/org/javers/repository/mongo/MongoE2EWithCustomHeadCollectionNameTest.groovy).
This is what my configuration code looks like.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.javers.spring")
@EnableMongoRepositories("org.javers.spring")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class JaversSpringMongoApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    MongoClient mongoClient;

    @Value("${db.name}")
    String dbName;

    @Bean
    public void mongoConfigJavers(){
        MongoRepository mongoRepository = new MongoRepository(getMongoDb(dbName),
                mongoRepositoryConfiguration()
                        .withSnapshotCollectionName("jv_custom_snapshots")
                        .withHeadCollectionName("jv_custom_head_id")
                        .build());
    }

    private MongoDatabase getMongoDb(String dbName) {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
    }


}
```

On running the code, the collections name are not changing. I have tried dropping the previous collection and running the code again. But, the names of collections are still coming as **jv_snapshots** and **jv_head_id** instead of  **jv_custom_snapshots** and **jv_custom_head_id**.
What else do I need to do or how can I find where am I going wrong??

Comment: Why the @Bean factory method is void  ?

Comment: Because I didn't understand what this function should return and how Javers mongo config will pick this bean?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the Bean name from *mongoConfigJavers* to *Javers*. Basically Javers framewrok automatically configures this Bean and this can be overwritten by defining a new bean with the same name. [Reference](https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#javers-instance-as-spring-bean)

New code looks something like this:

```
@Bean
public Javers javers(){
    MongoRepository mongoRepository = new MongoRepository(getMongoDb(dbName),
            mongoRepositoryConfiguration()
                    .withSnapshotCollectionName("jv_custom_snapshots")
                    .withHeadCollectionName("jv_custom_head_id")
                    .build());
    return JaversBuilder.javers()
            .registerJaversRepository(mongoRepository)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example bean configuration of Javers. [Further details](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/boot/mongo/JaversMongoAutoConfiguration.java#L78)

```
@Bean(name = "JaversFromStarter")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Javers javers() {
    logger.info("Starting javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo ...");

    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = initJaversMongoDatabase();

    MongoRepository javersRepository = createMongoRepository(mongoDatabase);

    JaversBuilder javersBuilder = TransactionalMongoJaversBuilder.javers()
            .registerJaversRepository(javersRepository)
            .withTxManager(mongoTransactionManager.orElse(null))
            .withProperties(javersMongoProperties)
            .withObjectAccessHook(javersMongoProperties.createObjectAccessHookInstance());

    plugins.forEach(plugin -> plugin.beforeAssemble(javersBuilder));

    return javersBuilder.build();
}
```

Just for information with ***the release of 6.10.0***, these collection names are also now configurable via Spring boot configuration files(**application.yml**)

#### 6.10.0

released on 2023-02-15

- [1254](https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/1260)
  Added the possibility to disable the schema management in Mongo Repository via application code.

  Usage:

  ```
        MongoRepository mongoRepository = new MongoRepository(getMongoDb(),
                mongoRepositoryConfiguration()
                        .withSnapshotCollectionName("jv_custom_snapshots_")
                        .withHeadCollectionName("jv_custom_head_id_")
                        .withSchemaManagementEnabled(false)
                        .build())
  ```

  See also [MongoE2EWithSchemaEnabledTest.groovy](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-persistence-mongo/src/test/groovy/org/javers/repository/mongo/MongoE2EWithSchemaEnabledTest.groovy)
- Made Mongo repository configuration parameters(*snapshotCollectionName, headCollectionName, schemaManagementEnabled*) configurable through Spring boot configuration files (`application.yml`)

Usage:

```yaml
  javers:
    snapshotCollectionName: "jv_custom_snapshots"
    headCollectionName: "jv_custom_head_id"
    schemaManagementEnabled: false
```